# 3 Cicles Problem: Minimizing the Distances Cost Function

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization, circles

I appreciate your assistance!
I’m working on locating a point that minimizes the sum of squared distances from a set of circles. The objective function to minimize is:

$$
E(x,y) = \sum_i \big( (x-w_i)^2 + (y-f_i)^2 - m_i^2 \big)^2
$$

With three circles in my scenario, I aim to determine this point. Despite calculating the partial derivatives, which include both ( x ) and ( y ), I’m unsure if an analytical solution exists or if I must resort to numerical methods.
Considering a numerical approach, I’ve thought about employing gradient descent but am uncertain how to apply it to both coordinates simultaneously. My initial strategy is:

-Start with random values for ( x ) and ( y ).

-Evaluate the cost function ( E(x,y) ).

-Derive the partial derivatives.
Apply a scaling factor ( K ) to the derivatives.

-Adjust ( x ) and ( y ) by adding the scaled derivatives.

-Re-evaluate from step 2, stopping if the cost function increases, or persist until it nearly vanishes.

Could you please explain if a numerical method is the only option for this problem and why an exact solution might not be attainable?

Comment: That’s not the sum of squared distances from a set of circles. The distance of the point $(x,y)$ from the circle of radius $m_i$ centred at $(w_i,f_i)$ is $|\sqrt{(x-w_i)^2+(y-f_i)^2}-m_i|$, so the sum of the squares of those distances would be

$$
\sum_i\left(\sqrt{(x-w_i)^2+(y-f_i)^2}-m_i\right)^2\;.
$$

What you wrote is the sum of the squared differences between the squared distances from the centres and the squared radii.

Comment: Whatever your true objective function is, Rather than approach it the way you have, consider instead supposing that $(x_0, y_0)$ is a local minimum. Choose some arbitrary direction $(u,v)$ to perturb it by a distance $t: E(t) = E(x_0 + tu, y_0 + tv)$.  Because $(x_0, y_0)$ is a minimum $\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} E(t) = 0$. This gives you an equation that must be true for all values of $u,v$. You can choose various values of $u,v$ that give you simpler equations to deal with, and use those to determine the values of $x_0, y_0$ for which they are true.